# Low contrast font color after upgrading 10.04 to 11.04

Tags: 11.04, unity

After upgrading from Ubuntu 10.04 to 11.04, the font on the top panel have a very low contrast and is hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ambiance theme the text colour is not black, but grey. You can change it by clicking Customize in the Appearance applet.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have the "New Wave" theme. Click the top-left icon, then type "appearance" followed by Enter, and pick a different theme. The contrast should be fine now, and the text on top panel readable.